# хотел поставить докер на debian 10, но не вышло

Tags: linux, debian, docker

в общем делал всё как всегда по инструкции на официальном сайте docker, делал это миллион раз и всё работало, но не в этот раз. добавил репы ключи и дальше sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package docker-ce is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'docker-ce' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package docker-ce-cli
E: Unable to locate package containerd.io
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'containerd.io'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'containerd.io'
 ЧТо за непорядок, система в роде чистая, не должно быть проблем.

Comment: Запусти скриптик репы установить

Comment: и как это сделать ? где взять скрипт

Comment: сделал, но тоже ругается sudo sh get-docker.sh
# Executing docker install script, commit: f45d7c11389849ff46a6b4d94e0dd1ffebca32c1
+ sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu buster Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: в общем я думаю его поставлю всё таки в ручном режиме, но всё же вопрос остаётся в силе чисто в теоретическом смысле, что за ошибки